# Is Linguistics going to pick up the weight of Indian Languages?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, formatting

The Indian Language Stack Exchange has been deleted from Area 51 proposals. This is immensely unpredicted considering this was a much requested and heavily required question answer forum.

Linguistics comes close but as a native Malayalam speaker, I worry the nuances of Middle Tamil wouldn't be picked up by non-Indians/Indian language specialists.

Also the wise variety of languages in India, a country whose states are divided on language, is just mind bogling. There are notable linguistic variations every 100km in any direction of this country.

How will linguistic.SE facilitate an influx of questions regarding Indian Languages? Should an IndianLanguage Learners SE be made similar to ELL SE?

Comment: What relevance does your being a "native Malayalam speaker" have to do with the "nuances of Middle Tamil"? Native Malayalam speakers don't have a magical ability to better understand Middle Tamil and in my experience native speakers are nearly always confused about linguistics to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what the scope of that site was supposed to be, but probably a lot of the material there would be off-topic here. For example, "What's the Punjabi word for 'dog'?", is "...." proper Tamil, "what does this inscription say?". We get a lot of questions about etymology, word-formation, phonology and syntax regarding Indian languages and those are on-topic, also computational questions about databases. There are also occasional questions [like this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/16909), where a user has a grammar-class kind of question: opinions are mixed on whether such questions are in the realm of linguistics. The main point is that there is a tendency for people to think that linguistics is "anything about language, except literature", but it isn't. If you can add some sample question, it would be easier to speak substantively.

Comment: so, do you suggest re-opening that site? or is there an alternative?

Comment: I don't know why it was deleted.

Comment: It would've been deleted for not having enough people sign up to commit to it.